# Avoiding problems with gpg-agent when running from scripts - gpg2

Tags: bash, gnupg, gpg-agent

I'm trying to use `gpg` to `--clearsign` a file (for debian packaging purposes) *from a script*.

I have an exported password-less `private-key.gpg` file and want to:

```
gpg --clearsign -o output input
```

I don't want to mess with the current user's `~/.gnupg` or `/run/user/$(id -u)/gnupg` because they *have nothing to do with my script*. Also, the script could be running in multiple instances simultaneously and I don't want them interfering with one another.

I thought that would be easy. Setup `$GNUPGHOME` to a temp dir and be done with it. But I cannot figure out how to get `gpg` to run in a script without messing with the user's standard configuration *at all*. It seems `gpg` has gone to great lengths to make it impossible to avoid the `gpg-agent` and `gpg-agent` insists on using global/hard-coded paths.

Can I keep *everything* under `$GNUPGHOME`? Or how do I safely use `gpg` from a shell script without influencing the user's config or use of `gpg` or other instances of my script?

### Details

Reading the [gpg docs](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/GPG-Configuration-Options.html) I see that:

```
--use-agent
--no-use-agent

    This is dummy option. gpg always requires the agent.
```

And [gpg-agent docs](https://www.gnupg.org/documentation/manuals/gnupg/Agent-Options.html) say:

```
--use-standard-socket
--no-use-standard-socket
--use-standard-socket-p

    Since GnuPG 2.1 the standard socket is always used.
    These options have no more effect. The command gpg-agent
    --use-standard-socket-p will thus always return success.
```

This "standard socket" is presumably in `/run/user/$(id -u)/gnupg` - so it seems I can't avoid gpg messing with the user's "normal" use of gpg.

Versions: gpg 2.1.18 on Debian 9 / stretch / stable

Comment: Not sure whether this is new, but apparently the socket directory on Linux depends on `GNUPGHOME`. From [GnuPG on ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GnuPG#gpg-agent): “_If you use non-default GnuPG home directory, you will need to edit all socket files to use the values of `gpgconf --list-dirs`. The socket names use the hash of the non-default GnuPG home directory, so you can hardcode it without worrying about it changing._” In this case you don’t need to worry about socket path collision.

Comment: @FranklinYu: as I wrote before I already tried messing with `$GNUPGHOME`. Have you actually gotten this to work?

Comment: Yes, it uses `/run/user/1001/gnupg/d.19dny8pcrzpq1uj8ykkupwfr/` as the directory of sockets on my machine. Another example, `GNUPGHOME=/tmp/gnupg gpgconf --list-dirs socketdir` gives me `/run/user/1001/gnupg/d.p63as1i1pzzqkuqzs6d175fn`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't stop gpg from creating files, would it help to give gpg a place to put them that's unique to the current process?

```
# Create a temporary directory for gpg.
dir="$(mktemp -d)"

# Remove the directory and its contents when the script exits.
trap '[[ ! -d "${dir}" ]] || rm -r "${dir}"' EXIT

# Put your private-key.gpg in the temporary directory.
$(your command here)

# Tell gpg to use the temporary directory.
gpg --homedir "${dir}" --clearsign -o output input
```

Comment: Alas, `gpg --homedir` is equivalent to me setting `$GNUPGHOME`. As I wrote: "I thought that would be easy. Setup `$GNUPGHOME` to a temp dir and be done with it".

But it will still use e.g. `/run/user/$(id -u)/gnupg` and there is no way to avoid that I know of yet.

Answer (score 1):

After multiple hours of searching the internet for some option to enable running multiple instances of `gpg-agent` with different gnupg homes I tried just restricting the access to the global socket location and it worked. It fell back to placing the socket files in the gnupg home directory. I used `bwrap` to do that. Here's the full command that worked: `bwrap --dev-bind / / --tmpfs /run/user/$(id -u)/gnupg gpg-agent ...`. Since your question is about scripts in general, you probably can't rely on `bwrap` being installed, so the next best thing is a shim that prevents `gpg-agent` from using the user's xdg runtime directory for its sockets.

After looking through the output of strace, the switch of location when running under `bwrap` to gnupg home seems to happen after a `stat` on `/run/user/${UID}/gnupg` is issued. Looking through the `gpg-agent.c` code this seems to do that check:

```c
  /* Check that it is a directory, owned by the user, and only the
   * user has permissions to use it.  */
  if (!S_ISDIR(sb.st_mode)
      || sb.st_uid != getuid ()
      || (sb.st_mode & (S_IRWXG|S_IRWXO)))
    {
      *r_info |= 4; /* Bad permissions or not a directory. */
      if (!skip_checks)
        goto leave;
    }
```

Using this we can just tell `gpg-agent` that the `/run/user/${UID}/gnupg` exists, but is not a directory, so it will fail the first of these checks.

Here's the code for a shim that does just that (could be better, but it works):

```c
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define STR_MAX 4096

#define MIN(a, b) (a < b ? a : b)
#define MAX(a, b) (a > b ? a : b)

// Set up checking stuff
#define MAX_UID_LEN 11

#define PREFIX_1 "/run/user"
#define PREFIX_2 "/var/run/user"

#define TEST_LEN_1 (sizeof(PREFIX_1) - 1 + 1 + MAX_UID_LEN + sizeof("/gnupg") - 1)
#define TEST_LEN_2 (sizeof(PREFIX_2) - 1 + 1 + MAX_UID_LEN + sizeof("/gnupg") - 1)

#define MAX_TEST_LEN MAX(TEST_LEN_1, TEST_LEN_2)

// Override stat function
int stat(const char *restrict pathname, struct stat *restrict statbuf) {
    int (*original_stat)(const char *restrict, struct stat *restrict) = dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "stat");

    // Call original stat function
    int retval = original_stat(pathname, statbuf);

    if (retval == 0) {
        // Check if a path we want to modify
        size_t pathlen = strnlen(pathname, STR_MAX);
        char path_check[MAX_TEST_LEN + 1];

        snprintf(path_check, MAX_TEST_LEN + 1, "%s/%u/gnupg", PREFIX_1, getuid());
        if (strncmp(pathname, path_check, MIN(MAX_TEST_LEN, pathlen)) == 0) {
            // Report a regular file with perms: rwxrwxrwx
            statbuf->st_mode = S_IFREG|0777;
        }

        snprintf(path_check, MAX_TEST_LEN + 1, "%s/%u/gnupg", PREFIX_2, getuid());
        if (strncmp(pathname, path_check, MIN(MAX_TEST_LEN, pathlen)) == 0) {
            // Report a regular file with perms: rwxrwxrwx
            statbuf->st_mode = S_IFREG|0777;
        }
    }

    return retval;
}
```

You can compile it with: `clang -Wall -O2 -fpic -shared -ldl -o gpg-shim.so gpg-shim.c` and then add it to `LD_PRELOAD` and it should then allow you to run multiple `gpg-agent`s as long as they have different gnupg homes.

I know this answer is really late, but I hope it can help some people that were, like me, looking for a way to run multiple `gpg-agent`s with different homedirs. (For my specific case, I wanted to run multiple `gpg-agent` instances to have keys cached different amounts of time).